# Entity Framework Update error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I am getting a voialation of Primary key error with the following code. I can't see for looking as to why this may be and I need to sort it out. Can anybody help with a fresh pair of eyes?

```
var events = (from e in nodes.Descendants("event")
                              select new Event
                              {
                                  Event_ID = int.Parse(e.Attribute("event_id").Value),
                                  Name = e.Attribute("name").Value,
                                  Code = e.Attribute("code").Value,
                                  Minute = e.Attribute("minute").Value != String.Empty ? int.Parse(e.Attribute("minute").Value) : 0,
                                  Minute_Extra = e.Attribute("minute_extra").Value != String.Empty ? int.Parse(e.Attribute("minute_extra").Value) : 0,
                                  Team = GetTeam(e.Attribute("team_id")),
                                  Last_Updated = DateTime.Parse((FormatDateTime(e.Attribute("last_updated").Value)))

                              });

foreach (Event matchEvent in events)
{

    //Check to see if this event exists
    if (match.Events.Any(o => o.Event_ID == matchEvent.Event_ID))
    {
        Event theEvent = (from m in match.Events
                          where m.Event_ID == matchEvent.Event_ID
                          select m).FirstOrDefault();

        //There is an event with this ID, so check its last updated flag
        if (theEvent.Last_Updated < matchEvent.Last_Updated)
        {
            //Update the current event
            theEvent.Event_ID = matchEvent.Event_ID;
            theEvent.Name = matchEvent.Name;
            theEvent.Code = matchEvent.Code;
            theEvent.Minute = matchEvent.Minute;
            theEvent.Minute_Extra = matchEvent.Minute_Extra;
            theEvent.Team = matchEvent.Team;
            theEvent.Last_Updated = matchEvent.Last_Updated;
        }

    }
    //If the event is not there we need to add it
    else
    {
        match.Events.Add(matchEvent);
    }

    myDb.SaveChanges();
```

UPDATE 1: The following is the error I get when SaveChanges() is called:

`{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Matches_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Matches'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

UPDATE 2: I am not using identity insert on the DB table for this as this is an import from a 3rd party Web Service where I need to retain all Ids. I am not sure if this will affect the update process with entity framework?

UPDATE 3: Ok well when I turn on identity insert the update is successful however I dont wish to have indentity insert on this table as the Ids are passed in from a WebService and I need to retain these Ids.

Comment: Which line is the error on? Does the error have anything in the message that could be helpful?

Comment: It's not that simple that you have forgot to mark the PK-property as 'Auto Generated'?

Comment: THE PK is not auto generated in this case, maybe thats my problem? This is basically running an import from a 3 rd party web Service where the IDs are already specified?

Comment: In fact this IS the issue as I have tried to add identity insert on the table and the update is successful. However I dont want Identity insert to be on the table as I have Ids coming from the import?

Comment: Maybe you should have the ID from the 3rd party as an index, and your own auto-update primary key.

Comment: I'm thinking that's the short term solution to this, but it would be nice if there was a way around it. Many thanks for your help and I will indeed use this approach for now.

Comment: No probs. Don't forget to come back and let us know if you come up with a solution!

Comment: With that PK violation, which entity is `dbo.Matches`? Is that `Event` entity? If you run a SQL profiler trace, is the ID that being passed through already exist in that table? If you've got a PK on a field which is NOT an identity, you need to do some data inspection/validation in your DAL before you attempt the insert. (either that, or go with @Matt Ellen's solution). I've had problems with third party data inserts too - the end result was i had no referential integrity in the DB. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, because I'm not too hot on Entity Framework, but do you need this line?

```
theEvent.Event_ID = matchEvent.Event_ID;
```

It comes just after

```
//There is an event with this ID, so check its last updated flag
if (theEvent.Last_Updated < matchEvent.Last_Updated)
```

and I would think it's redundant, and also might cause a Primary Key error, as I don't think you can assign to a primary key once it's been created.

**Update**

Did a quick search, and you can't update a primary key once it's been created, so I'm pretty sure this is where your error is.

See this SO answer: [Update primary key value using entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367751/update-primary-key-value-using-entity-framework)

Comment: Thanks for this, I have taken this out but STILL getting the same error. It still seems to be trying to insert a duplicate record. I'm bemused.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem lies when you are updating the `Event_ID` property.  The object you requested from your database through the `match` DBContext already contains that same `Event_ID` as the Web service. Therefore, there is no need to update this value

```
if (theEvent.Last_Updated < matchEvent.Last_Updated) 
{
  //Update the current event
  theEvent.Event_ID = matchEvent.Event_ID;  // <-- Delete this line.
  ...
}
```

You may ask, why it matters since both values are the same? As it so happens the DBContext keeps track of your objects and its changes.  In the context itself, each property has an original and current value.  When you assigned the same value to the `Event_ID` the context is going to interpret it as a compleately different value even though is the same.

I hope this helps.