# Choosing primary key value in LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm creating an asp.net site that used linq to sql to create, edit and delete cars and race results. Each car has it's own number which has been set as the primary key. Each result has a result number, and there is a many-to-one relationship between the results and cars.

To create a new car object I use the Car DataContext, which automatically updates the database as requires using the DataContext.SubmitChanges() function. However it won't update the primary key, instead choosing a new one by incrementing the largest current value.

Since each car's number is important, is there any way to choose the primary key value using this method? Or should I make the car ID separate and use a separate piece of code to make sure the ID is unique?

Comment: You have auto increment (identity) key for your car table. That is why you are getting incremented primary key value. Can you paste your Car table `create` statement in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you aluded to in your question, keeping the `Car` number separate from its Id is the way to go. The reason for this is that it is possible that two cars *could* at some point have the same number, in addition to the fact that the database is choosing its own value for the Id anyway.

Just add another field to your `Car` table to record its number and you should be good to go.

See [Update primary key value using entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367751/update-primary-key-value-using-entity-framework) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that. The reason I was using the primary key as the Car number was because the car numbers need to be distinct. I'll implement a new field and add some logic to check that it's unique.