# How to update primary key from Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have Table

```
eventid int -- not PK key but with autoincrement
jobid -- PK autoincrement disabled
userid  int   -- PK autoincrement disabled
```

To update jobID I do following:

```
var itemforupdate = context.table.where(n=>n.eventid == someparameter).FirstorDefault()
```

I get the item from database correctly, but when assigning:

```
itemforupdate.jobID = 5;
context.SaveChanges();
```

after `context.SaveChanges()` I get the error:

> The property 'jobID' is part of the object's key information and
>   cannot be modified

How to update jobID from Entity Framework to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm no expert with entity framework but can't you set the object's key to be eventid (since it's an auto-increment column anyway)?

Comment: i just get item from database using eventid that is unique and trying to update jobid from EF but it gives error

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367751/update-primary-key-value-using-entity-framework

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Updating primary key columns is not a good practice with EntityFramework.  It confuses EF because it changes the identity of the object, and makes keeping the in-memory copy and the in-database copy of the data in sync very problematic.  So it's not allowed.

Just don't update primary keys.  Instead delete one row and insert a new one.

Alternatively you can update the primary key directly with a stored procedure or other query.

Comment: Delete one row and insert a new one works ! Thks